# Angular HTTP POST to ASP.NET Core 6 complex parameter null

Tags: c#, typescript, .net-core, angular14

When Angular 14 does this HTTP `POST` call:

```
 this.http.post<ProjectDto>(baseUrl + 'Projects/CreateProject', this.projectCreateInitDto).subscribe({
```

to the controller (ASP.NET Core 6):

```
[Route("CreateProject")]
[HttpPost("{dto}")]
public ActionResult<ProjectAPIDto> CreateProject(ProjectAPICreateInitDto dto)
{
    var x = dto;
}
```

The controller `dto` is always null.

Things I've tried (and failed):

1. Added `[FromBody]`, which shouldn't be necessary since the dto is a complex argument; I've used the above structure to pass integers and that works.
2. Converted the Angular argument to JSON string and passed that as a string. Since 'string' is technically a simple argument, I added `[FromBody]` to the controller where the argument was just `[FromBody] string dto`. Also fails, without `FromBody`.

I don't understand:

- if/when `{dto}` is needed in the `HttpPost` attribute, but is seems to me that it should be there to indicate what the `CreateProject` argument is.
- how to add argument(s) to the `Route` attribute - if/when that should be used.

Researched a lot and still failing.

Thanks.

Comment: .NET 6 is not Core. Attribute {dto} is not needed, but HttpPost. What is the javascript object or interface that resolves from projectCreateInitDto ?

Comment: I think you don't need `{dto}` try remove and see. because `{}` is used to pass parameter in routes. In your route 'Projects/CreateProject' you are passing nothing in the route, for example 'Projects/CreateProject/dto1'

Comment: @medmorad that's for GET

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: .NET 5, 6, 7 ***ARE*** in fact the new "Core" versions - the next versions after .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @marc_s yes but not at compatibility or framework level.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: what do you mean by *not at framework level* ? .NET 6 ***IS*** part of the .NET Core family of cross-platform runtimes - so **YES** also at the framework level, it ***IS*** .NET **Core** (not the old/legacy/full/Windows-only .NET framework) ....

Comment: don't understand ".NET 6 is not core"; every version since .NET 5.0 has been core.  I am struggling to understand what the {"{dto"} does... I think (?) that arguments are URI (query string args) by default if they are basic data types like int, bool, string, .... and I think there can only be one argument?  
I tried adding [FromBody] so NET would find the argument there; I did that because at one point I converted the argument (an object - class - with a lot of args like int, bool, string.  
I converted JSON in Angular and sent that as a string, which then would be a single URI argument.

Comment: ProjectCreateInitiDto is simply
export class ProjectCreateInitDto
{  public title: string; description: string, ...}  the equivalent on the NET side is identical accept for being Pascal case (leading uppercase).